# how to mock inetaddress.getlocalhost().gethostname() to throw an exception

Tags: java, testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I want my junit test coverage to include default method from interface. Following is the method from the interface

```
public default String getServerAddress() {
    try {
        return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
    } catch (Exception e) {
         return null;
    }
}
```

My target is to cover exception part of this method. So i probably need to mock InetAddress to make it throw exception. But i'm not sure how?
I tried to mock inetAddress and do the following but doesn't seem to be working:

```
when(inetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()).thenThrow(Exception.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;

@RunWith( PowerMockRunner.class )
@PrepareForTest( NetworkReader.class )
public class Tests {

    @Test
    public void testGetServerAddress() {
        mockStatic(NetworkUtil.class);
        when(NetworkReader.getLocalHostname()).thenThrow(new Exception("exception message));
    
        // Here you could test your interface. 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm sorry i am not using power-mockito and can't switch to it for one method.. is there any other way?

Comment: You are very welcome ! I would say unfortunately not or at least this I am aware of as of now. Specifically, with power mockito you can mock static methods, while with mockito this cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock static methods even with Mockito (since 3.4.0). See [docs](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#48) or [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods).

The other possibility would be to wrap the static call into your own class and inject this into the final usage place. Your wrapper object could be then mocked in a standard way.